# How to read a checkbox already checked ON?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code on materialize

it's working, but when the button is already checked, won`t work for some reason

so, if there is :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test1" onclick="this.form.submit()" checked="checked">
```

there will be the lever ON but when i click it off it won`t submit the form

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```html
<?php if (isset($_POST['test1'])){ echo "working"; } ?>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Dashboard</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize.min.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> </head>
<form method="post">
  <div class="switch"> <label> Off <input type="checkbox" name="test1" onclick="this.form.submit()" checked="checked"> <span class="lever" ></span> On </label> </div>
</form>
</script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

Any help is really appreciate

Thank you

Comment: Where is the snippet? There is no code

Comment: Not working means you are not getting message `working`? on submit?

Comment: correctif you take out the checked="checked" and the lever is off then when you switch it on will work

Comment: there is a link with the code : http://robofarm.ro/ceres2/test2.txt

Comment: @MariusCristian So this input checkbox should trigger the form submit is it? only when the checkbox is on? and should not trigger when the checkbox is off!

Comment: ok so , try this code like this: <input type="checkbox" name="test1" onclick="this.form.submit()" > without "checked attribute", when you check the box/lever you will see the message "working" but if the box/lever are already ON and if you want to switch it OFF won`t work

Comment: @MariusCristian form is submitted successfully. You  are not getting message because noramally when check box not checked , its value will not be passed in submit request. So your form submitted but `$_POST['test1']` will not get so you dont get message

Comment: so, how can we fix that?

Comment: It is not the issue. It is normal behavior. But if you want value of uncheked checkbox also you can manage it by hidden field

Comment: well when the box is checked there will be a mysql value changed 0/1 but when i uncheck the box, i want the mysql value to go back to 0 ... this is why i need the forms for ...

Comment: There is no value to checkbox. Give it any value like '1' or 'yes'. But not 0.

Comment: can you post a sample please? thank you

Comment: thing like this - <input type="checkbox" name="test1" onclick="this.form.submit()" checked="checked" value="yes">

Comment: is not working.

Comment: As you are keeping the checkbox property checked, when you click it, it becomes unchecked and so $_POST['test1'] is not set upon form submission. And when the form is displayed again after submission, the checkbox is checked by default. So the same thing will be repeated and it will never echo...

Comment: i fix it. thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

i have the answer but i don`t know why i can`t post it
so there is the syntax

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['test1'])){ echo "working"; } ?>
```

and on the action form:

```
<form action="test.php?test1=true" method="post">
```

and then it`s working with the checked attribute
thank you